# Search bar search from NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios, nstimezone

I want to make a search bar where the user will type only a portion of timezone & it will show the full timezone from my array, if exist in the array. e.g. if the user type "dhaka", the search bar will show the full string "Asia/Dhaka". Is that possible to do? If possible please guide me the way. Thanks a lot in advance for the help.

Comment: May be this will prove helpful- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/ToolbarSearch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009461

Answer (score 0):

its possible use UISearchBar object ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) to search.

Display results implement UISearchDisplayController  ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008225)) and its Delegate ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008226)). Add a simple array of your timezone/city to its dataSource. Each time the user type in a character shouldReloadTableForSearchString will be called so do a query to find timezone/city matches

Comment: what u r saying is for table view. But i want to make it not for table view. just a search bar & searching from an array. Thank u for ur effort.

Comment: If your looking for a autocomplete feature check this project out ([link](https://github.com/hoteltonight/HTAutocompleteTextField))

Answer (score 0):

**There are many logic but i put my logic here :**

Take Two `NSMutableArray` and **add one array to  another array** in `ViewDidLoad` method such like,

```
self.listOfTemArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // array no - 1
self.ItemOfMainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"YorArrayList", nil]; // array no - 2 

[self.listOfTemArray addObjectsFromArray:self.ItemOfMainArray]; // add 2array to 1 array
```

**And Write following delegate Method of UISearchBar**

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
        NSString *name = @"";
        NSString *firstLetter = @"";

    if (self.listOfTemArray.count > 0)
         [self.listOfTemArray removeAllObjects];

        if ([searchText length] > 0)
        {
                for (int i = 0; i < [self.ItemOfMainArray count] ; i = i+1)
                {
                        name = [self.ItemOfMainArray objectAtIndex:i];

                        if (name.length >= searchText.length)
                        {
                                firstLetter = [name substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
                                //NSLog(@"%@",firstLetter);

                                if( [firstLetter caseInsensitiveCompare:searchText] == NSOrderedSame )
                                {
                                    // strings are equal except for possibly case
                                    [self.listOfTemArray addObject: [self.ItemOfMainArray objectAtIndex:i]];
                                    NSLog(@"=========> %@",self.listOfTemArray);
                                }
                         }
                 }
         }
         else
         {
             [self.listOfTemArray addObjectsFromArray:self.ItemOfMainArray ];
         }

        [self.tblView reloadData];
}
}
```

Output Show in your `Consol.`

**This code might helpful for you.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSPredicate for this

Like

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
if(searchText.length < 1){
//reload with full array
return;
}
    NSArray *timeZones = ...;//yourfullArray;
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(timeZoneName CONTAINS [cd] %@)",searchText];//if ur array is only strings then change format to @"(self CONTAINS [cd] %@)"
         NSArray *filterdZones = [timeZones filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"filterdZones %@",filterdZones);
}
```

**NOTE:not tested the code**